# Is it possible to import such data from Excel to R?

Tags: r, excel, import

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxmd8.png [1]

This table has been converted from PDF to Excel. As can be seen, in Excel, the headings have multiple layers to them (Potential Created, Potential Utilised, etc). Is it possible to import this as it is to R? Or does the data have to be properly organized before doing so?

I'm not aware of how to make the image of the data I'm working with appear on this site. I've posted a link to the image above.

Comment: Have you checked this very useful and complete discussion on the matter: https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/379 ?

Comment: you can use `skip` attribute in `read.table` or `read.csv` functions